# Why is navigator.cpuClass incorrect?

Tags: javascript, client-side

I am trying to acquire the CPU type of visitors from Javascript using navigator.cpuClass in order to offer them the correct download.  In my tests I have run into an example of navigator.cpuClass returning "Win32" when expect "Win64".  The systeminfo utility on my PC returns:

Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11 GenuineIntel ~2400 Mhz (Q6600) which is further described at:
http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29765

Can anyone tell me why Javascript is not seeing a 64 bit CPU?  I need to reliably detect that CPU...

Comment: Just offer what you have and let users decide what they want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are using a 32 bit browser. Trying out the samples from [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlhiaix.php), I get the same results (`Win32`) even though I'm running a 64 bit OS (with a 32 bit build of Chrome).

However, in my case, Chrome's `appVersion` string indicates that it runs under the Wow64 emulation layer. Perhaps you can find such hints for others browsers as well.

Generally, you can't detect the CPU class *reliably* because you never know whether your browser took the red or the blue pill.

A pragmatic solution would be to offer a default choice based on what your browser returns, and allow the user to switch to a 64 bit version. Since most 32 bit software runs flawlessly in a 64 bit environment (as proved by this case), most users won't notice if they pick the 'wrong' download.

Comment: I also get that WOW64 from navigator.appVersion.  I will have to test that out and see. Looks like that could be the better hint.

Comment: @Optimal Solutions: I added some further notes.